# How to get IDEs (VS Code) to work with syntax highlighting with Protobufs (Python)

Tags: python, ide, protocol-buffers

I am using VS Code, but I suspect the following problem exists across all IDEs.

---

When compiling a protobuf file (`.proto`) to Python (`_pb2.py`), the Messages *will be available as classes, but Google's mechanism to expose the classes is difficult for IDEs to discover*.

For instance, with the following toy example

`person.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  string address = 2;
  int32 age = 3;
}
```

if I run

```bash
> protoc -I=. --python_out=. person.proto
```

it will generate a `person_pb2.py` file that will have a `Person` class that I can create an object from, looking something like this:

```py
from person_pb2 import Person

me = Person(name="me", address="heaven", age=2)
```

---

But the line `from person_pb2 import Person` will be highlighted as an error.

Specifically, in VS Code with Pylance installed, it will say

> "Person" is unknown import symbol   *[Pylance (reportAttributeAccessIssue)]*
>
> (import) Person: Unknown

The reason for this is clear: if I were to look at the `person_pb2.py` file **there is no top level object `Person` exported**!  This will be true for any protobuf messages, at any depth.  They all get mangled into complicated objects and then populated to the runtime via

```py
_builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, globals())
_builder.BuildTopDescriptorsAndMessages(DESCRIPTOR, 'person_pb2', globals())
```

This is a very strange edge case for populating the environment that I wouldn't really expect the IDEs to discover.

So, what can I do - or what do most people do - to have the IDE properly identify protobufs?

For now, I am just littering all my code with `# type: ignore` annotation, which is not ideal, since I'm "solving" the problem by just turning off the tool.  Is there a better option?

---

[To be clear, I currently "solve" this by doing things like `from person_pb2 import Person # type: ignore` in order to turn off Pylance's complaints. But I actually like Pylance's advice... the problem is that Google is hiding its exposed objects through this weird `globals()` trick.]

Comment: are you able to show the `person_pb2.py` file ?

Comment: What do you mean by "show" the file?  I can see the file.  But all protobuf files (at least in Python), use very non-standard syntax. This is the core issue, the syntax of the Python flavor of protobuf is so weird and far from best practices that the IDEs cannot discover the elements inside of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can enable [PYI](https://docs.fileformat.com/programming/pyi/) using by adding `--pyi_out=.` to your `protoc` command. VS Code should then be able to annotate the stubs:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=. \
--python_out=. \
--pyi_out=. \
person.proto
```

> **NOTE** This currently doesn't extend to gRPC ([Type hints in gRPC Python stubs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/29041)) but should be fine for protobuf Messages etc.

Comment: I think this will be the right solution, but it doesn't work with Proto3.  I'll accept it, but I haven't _actually_ been able to verify that it does what I need.

Comment: It works with `proto3` which I know from personal experience. I suspect you have a different issue. See [code generator](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/main/python#code-generator)

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  I'm not sure why it said it wouldn't work, but I tried again and got it to work this time.